# flavor , how to change different flavor main activity

Tags: android

how to change different flavor MainActivity

```
(android.intent.action.MAIN, android.intent.category.LAUNCHER)
```

can i set different default activity for every flavor?

Comment: what is "flavor" in your case?

Comment: you can have a Manifest for each flavour

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are asking if you can change any activity to a launcher activity, Yes. you can do it by changing the activity in which you specify the launcher.